# Отличия и преимущества БД

Tags: android, sqlite, memory, realm, ormlite

В скором времени придётся реализовывать в своём приложении базу данных.
Бегло ознакомившись, выделил SQLite, Realm, ORMlite, GreenDAO, Memory.
Но по официальной документации немного сложно сделать вывод о данных базах.
Хотелось бы узнать от Вас дорогие разработчики с чем лучше иметь дело и в каких случаях.

Comment: Рекомендую использовать Realm. ORMLite, GreenDAO и тп. лишь прослойка к SQLite, страдает скорость и реализация. Чистый SQL несколько харкорден, составить правильный и оптимальный запрос иногда весьма хлопотно, а работать с курсором не всегда удобно, хотя и быстр. Так же окружение для работы SQLite в android довольно "многословно" в части необходимого для работы кода. Realm 100% noSQL ORM, быстрая, удобная, лаконичная .. недостаток - около 4 Мб сама подключаемая библиотека, но оно того определенно стоит.

Answer (score 5):

Вы поставили в один ряд несколько разные вещи.

`SQLite` и `Realm` – это `СУБД`.

`ORMlite` и `GreenDAO` – это библиотеки, реализующие технологию `ORM` (первая поддерживает многие `СУБД`, в частности и `SQLite`, вторая – только `SQLite`).

Можно использовать, например, напрямую `SQLite` без `ORM`, можно использовать `SQLite` с помощью прослоек в виде `ORMlite` или `GreenDAO`.

Если Вы до этого момента не работали с базами данных, то я бы посоветовал сначала покопаться с *голым* `SQLite`, чтобы понять, как это все работает изнутри. Как поймете – попробуйте использовать `SQLite` с помощью одной из `ORM`-библиотек. А уже после этого можете попробовать `Realm`.

Если в Вашем приложении Вы *активно* работаете с базой данный, я бы посоветовал что-нибудь из `ORM`-систем (ибо это удобнее, но в скорости проиграете).

Подробнее можете почитать по нижеследующим ссылкам:

[SQLite, ORMs, NoSQL: what Android developers use and why](http://greenrobot.org/android/sqlite-orms-nosql-what-android-developers-use-and-why/)

[Сравнительное тестирование девяти ORM для Android](https://habrahabr.ru/post/281226/)

Comment: Realm в большинстве операций не уступает по скорости SQLite. Очень быстрая noSQL ORM

Answer (score 2):

ИМХО, если хочешь что-то сильно кастомизируемое и гибкое, то это `SQLite` - это создание чистых `SQL` запросов.

Если что-то быстрое качественное и довольно мощное, то это - `Realm`. Все ORM библиотеки медленные по сравнению с этими двумя `СУБД`

Answer (score 1):

Если вам требуется скорость то используйте голый sqlite и не используйте orm. Они все очень отстают по скорости. Если вам нужно хранить простые данные то можно использовать Cupboard. Она очень простая и удобная. На втором месте по скорости вроде Realm, но весит он много, т.к. тянет нативные зависимости для разных процессоров. Можно конечно указать в конфиге конкретные процессоры. Еще есть библиотека Requery. Она очень гибкая